# Gui form created via ironPython freeze while processing

Tags: c#, ironpython, python-multithreading

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Drawing")
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")

from System.Drawing import Point
from System.Windows.Forms import Application, Button, Form, Label

class HelloWorldForm(Form):

    def __init__(self):
        self.Text = 'writeLogInfo'

        self.label = Label()
        self.label.Text = "writeLogInfo"
        self.label.Location = Point(50, 50)
        self.label.Height = 30
        self.label.Width = 200

        self.count = 0

        button = Button()
        button.Text = "Click Me"
        button.Location = Point(50, 100)

        button.Click += self.buttonPressed

        self.Controls.Add(self.label)
        self.Controls.Add(button)

    def buttonPressed(self, sender, args):
        print 'The label *used to say* : %s' % self.label.Text
        self.count += 1
        self.label.Text = "You have clicked me %s times." % self.count  


        for i in range(100):
          host.WriteInfoOnPanel("Test : " + str(i))
          host.Pause(300)

form = HelloWorldForm()
Application.Run(form)
```

I have prepared above IronPython script which creates gui and in for loop writes some info on main GUI.

My main gui exposes WriteInfoOnPanel function and runs pythons script:

```
_scriptEngine = Python.CreateEngine();
_mainScope = _scriptEngine.CreateScope();

var scriptSource = scriptEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(pathToScriptFile, Encoding.Default, SourceCodeKind.File);

_mainScope.SetVariable("host", _hostContract);
scriptSource.Execute(_mainScope);
```

Unfortunately while form opens and I click button it freeze till for loop ends.

Are there any good practise how to cope with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the UI responsive during processing any long-running tasks need to be run on a background thread. Use something like [`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx). If the background thread needs to change the UI, use [`Control.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx) to ensure that those updates are properly handled (all UI updates must occur on the thread that created it; `Control.Invoke` takes care of that).

Comment: thanks, I managed to to that by Task which is started from C# and exposed to python, I knew that it is also possible to use C# Thread directly from ironPython